# How to set to null JDialog after it was setVisible(false)?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have created `JDialog` and set it `setUndecorated(true)` - it has no default "Close" button. This `JDialog` class is created every time when some button on main `JFrame` is pressed. This `JDialog` dialog contains button "Cancel" which has `MouseListener`:

```
...
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    setVisible(false);
    // How to set this JDialog class to null - release the resources?
}
...
```

So I want set this JDialog instance to `null` - because every time button pressed on `JFrame` creates new `JDialog` instance - and that is using the resources. How can I resolve this issue?

**EDIT**

I found that if I each time create new `JDialog` on mouse click and then set it visible - `JDialog` window appears not well validated for some milliseconds, after that is OK. So I think more efficient is to create new `JDialog` instance, and then each time set it `setVisible(true)` or `setVisible(false)` when mouse clicked on some `JFrame/JDialog` buttons.

Comment: Yes, I had in mind an instance.. (English is not my native, so sometimes it could be mistakes from my side).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `dispose()` on the JDialog to free the resource although I've heard that memory leaks can still occur, especially with regards to soft and strong references.

---

Note that this statement in your question is confusing:

> So I want set this JDialog class to null

You cannot set a class to null, only an instance variable.

Comment: No, I have tried to experiment: setVisible(false); dispose(); and then setVisible(true); - and the dialog appears again - so it means the class still exists..

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis: as long as you keep viable references to the object, then yes it will still exist. It won't be possible to gc it unless there are no viable references. You cannot test it as you are doing and expect otherwise.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis as described in the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose() the resources *are* released, but `setVisible(true)` rebuilds the dialog.

Comment: @Qwerky Thanks indeed, this question is now answered. setVisible(false); and then dispose(); is enough.

Comment: @kleopatra: I wasn't happy with my answer to the textAction question in that I could not think of a way of listening to the clipboard's state without polling it.